# export data to JSON through Catalyst framework

Tags: php, mysql, json, d3.js, catalyst

I've created a database using MySQL and connected it to Catalyst framework in order to create a web interface.
I have to visualize my data using [d3.js](http://www.d3js.org) which gets data in JSON format.

I have created a php script which queries the database and exports the result of the query in JSON format.

Unfortunately, I haven't managed to find a way to use my php script inside catalyst. Is there a better way to query the database and export data in JSON format in order to use them in my d3.js chart?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about the perl Catalyst framework, right? Because the introduction of PHP into the mix sounds highly irregular.

Comment: yes, I am talking about perl catalyst framework. I thought that I could use php inside catalyst but now I understand that this is not possible and I'm trying to figure out alternatives. I've managed to query the database inside a controller and stored the query result in a variable which then I stash but I cannot understand how to export the query in JSON format in order to use it in my d3.js chart

Comment: OK. See my answer for further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Catalyst::View::JSON as recommended by Julien, but for the simple case:

```
=== SomeController.pm ===

package MyApp::Controllers::SomeController;

use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Catalyst::Controller';

use JSON;

sub my_json_action :Local {
    my ($self, $c, @args) = @_;
    my $result = ... some process or logic ...
    $c->res->body(to_json($result))
}

1;
```

That should return a JSONified version of `$result` to d3.js

If you are writing a lot of AJAX code in your app, I would definitely recommend getting your head around the C::V::JSON approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can render JSON through [Catalyst::View::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aView%3a%3aJSON).

```
sub my_json_action :Local {
    my ($self, $c, @args) = @_;
    my $result = ... some process or logic ...

    $c->stash(
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'array' => [1,2],
    );

    $c->forward('MyApp::View::JSON');
}
```

This would produce the following JSON:

```
{"foo":"bar","array":[1,2]}
```

In MyApp.pm, you can confifur the behavior or VIEW::JSON:

```
__PACKAGE__->config->{'View::JSON'} = {
        allow_callback  => 1,    # defaults to 0
#       callback_param  => 'bgm', # defaults to 'callback'
#       expose_stash    => [ qw(id status file error) ], # defaults to everything
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have found this as well but I cannot completely understand how should I use it.Could you please elaborate more?many thanks